# Pinging the internet to check for connectivity

Tags: python-3.x

While attempting to find the simplest way of checking for a valid Internet connection I found this:

```
os.system("ping google.com")
```

However, I can't seem to use it. It just runs in a loop seemingly forever regardless of what i do with with it.

Output:

> PING google.com (172.217.6.206) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from
>   lga25s54-in-f206.1e100.net (172.217.6.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55
>   time=61.8 ms 64 bytes from lga25s54-in-f206.1e100.net (172.217.6.206):
>   icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=61.7 ms 64 bytes from
>   lga25s54-in-f206.1e100.net (172.217.6.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55
>   time=61.9 ms 64 bytes from lga25s54-in-f206.1e100.net
>
> --- google.com ping statistics --- 7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6009ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
>   61.666/61.784/61.910/0.203 ms

So my question is how can I use this line with some kind of logic? In other words how can I use it in this respect (or something similar):

```
if os.system("ping google.com") == (some condition):
    some logic
```

Comment: the reason it runs in a loop forever is because that’s how the ping utility works when you call it like that from the cli

Comment: you cant use ping because it runs forever, and also os.system does not return what the program prints

Comment: :( my hopes and dreams...

Answer (score 1):

If your want to check only the internet connection then I guess this should serve your purpose

```
import requests

def check_internet_connection(url='http://www.google.com/', timeout=1):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:

        return False

print(check_internet_connection())
```

EDIT:

This could would check if connection is there or not using *popen*

```
import os
a = os.popen('ping -c 1 google.com').read()
if a:
    print('Internet connection working')
else:
    print('Internet connection Error')
```

Comment: Thanks but I have other ways of checking for an Internet connection already but that's not what I was asking for.

Comment: I have updated the answer , but you need to use _popen_ since os.system would not save the output